# Visio reverse engineer database files with INT extension to ER diagram

Tags: database, visio

I am using a legacy EHR system. Users input data through a front end. Data can be queried using a query tool. The tool allows data sources or tables to be viewed and reports to be generated. I see Visio allows databases to be reverse engineered into a ER diagram. The data sources associated with this database are INT, DEF and TD extensions. Does Visio allow you to reverse engineer a group of data sources into an ER diagram?

Comment: Erwin will let you do it.

Comment: Is this the CA ERwin Data Modeler? Is it freeware or can a trial version perform the reverse engineering I need?

Comment: Yes CA ERwin Data Modeler. you can do 25 tables in the trial version.